# Changing type using the "string" name

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I'm looking for a method to change the type of a value to the type that is provided in a string value.
For example, we're always going to be provided strings, so if I'm provided `"int"` I'd like to change from `string` to `int`.

I've tried the following, but the issue is that `GetConverter()` seems to look at the type despite using `"int"` as the `dataType` below, which means it converts to `string` in this case.

```
TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dataType).ConvertFromString(paramValue)
```

I'm not tied to using reflection if there is a more simple manner in which to accomplish this.

Comment: `Type.GetType(typeName)`, e.g. `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(Type.GetType("System.Int32"))...`

Comment: What they say ^^ , _but_ remember to never trust user input. The string's content may not match any type, be empty, be null ...